# How can I get the file with the oldest LastWriteTime in a directory?

Tags: powershell

If I have a full-path with a wildcard, how can I get the file with the oldest LastWriteTime?

```
$fullpath = "myFolder:\foooBar*.txt"
$theOldestFile = # What to write to get among the 
                 #fooBar*.txt that has the max LastWriteTime?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

like this:

```
$fullpath = "myFolder:\foooBar*.txt"
$theOldestFile = dir $fullpath | sort lastwritetime | select -First 1
```

Comment: Is it possible that 'dir' command does not work within a function that belongs to an imported-module?

Comment: try using get-childitem ... or do you have some scope variable issue?

Comment: Didn't work. I think the PS-Drive which I create even with GLOBAL scope is not reachable from a function that belongs to an imported-module. Possible?

Comment: When you create the psdrive? in same module? after/before module is loaded? in other module? in $profile?